# opening the link only in IE browsers

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to restrict users to open the email link only in IE or Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869348/how-to-restrict-users-to-open-the-email-link-only-in-ie-or-mozilla)

Hi,
i am sending an mail link like this:

http://localhost/abc/RFalse&format&retururl=/abc/Reports/main.aspx&mailid=surya

from my application to an user,is there any way that i can make sure or check so that this link can only be opened in  **IE browser**,

Condition

when they user try to opening in any other browser it should give an alert message   telling him to **open in IE browser only.**

any help would be great, hope my Question is  clear

thanks
Kumar

Comment: No can do! User controls user's computer.

Comment: Please don't post the same question again, just because you didn't like the answers you got.

Answer (score 2):

The question is clear. the answer is: not possible.

Change the link to a page where there is a conditional code to show a link or not.

Here is the code on the page you mail the link to

```
<!--[if IE]>
<a href="real_link_for_ie_users.html">You have a browser I have decided to support</a>
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
I apologise, but for some reason you are using a browser that I have decided not to support
<![endif]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could check the user-agent on the server-side or via JavaScript and display a corresponding message. But I wouldn't recommend to do that. Better make the page work with "real" browsers instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely possible, but bad practice. You should use Web Standards to ensure it works in any browser.

However, if you must, add this JavaScript code to your page:

```
if (navigator.appName!='Internet Explorer') { alert('This website can only be viewed with Internet Explorer'); history.go(-1); }
```

Be warned, however, that this will only work if JavaScript is enabled.